# Cannot work out a php str_replace() to remove comma

Tags: php, string, str-replace

In a PHP project, I have:

```
$string = "1,555";

str_replace(',', '', $string);
echo $string; //is still 1,555
```

str_replace does not remove the comma. If I var_dump. I get `string(5) "1,555"`

Any ideas? I just simply need to remove the commas so I can compute.

Comment: no attempt to capture return value, VTC as typo

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$string = str_replace(',', '', $string);
```